# Shared Worksheet with Macros in Excel 2003

Tags: excel

Is it possible to have a shared worksheet with macros? We have created a sheet with a basic macro (enter in name, auto-populates the date). But now the sheet can only be edited one at a time. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like macros should be allowed in shared worksheets.  I'm not sure what you mean by *can only be edited one at a time*, whether this means one user at a time or one cell at a time (i.e. the macro is not updating the cells when it should be).

However, take a look at [this Egghead Cafe thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30724903/macros-dont-work-in-shar.aspx) for one possible cause to your problem.  Also take a look [here](http://www.exceladvisor.net/sub/6_shared.htm) for a list of restrictions on usage of shared worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cannot edit macros in a shared workbook (if that's what you're referring to). In other words, if multiple people have the spreadsheet open, none of the macros are editable.

Link: http://www.exceladvisor.net/sub/6_shared.htm

Edit: Oops. Same link as previous answerer. Sorry.

Update: Some more links related to this:

http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002833_Using_Macros_in_Protected_Workbooks.html
http://www.adras.com/Can-macros-be-viewed-or-edited-while-in-shared-mode.t62996-5.html